# Error adding n enum namespace inside structure

Tags: c++, c++14

I have an error when I add a parameter of class inside the structure. I don't know why, but inserting a simple variable of type namespace::enum variable with a `static_cast` doesn't make an error. What I try to do, is to insert all my enums in a vector of structure

namespace code

```
namespace plazza {
    enum Ingredients {
        Doe,
        Tomato, 
        Gruyere,
        Ham
    };
}
```

Structure

```
typedef struct s_stock {
    plazza::Ingredients ingredient;
    int quantity;
} t_stock;
```

Class

```
class Kitchen {
public:
    Kitchen(int multiplier, int numCooks, int cookingTime);
    ~Kitchen();
private:
    int _multiplier;
    int _numCooks;
    int _cookingTime;
    std::vector<t_stock> _stock;
    plazza::Ingredients ginger;
};
```

Code

```
Kitchen::Kitchen(int multiplier, int numCooks, int cookingTime) {
    _multiplier = multiplier;
    _numCooks = numCooks;
    _cookingTime = cookingTime;
    // How I think it should be
    _stock[0].ingredient = plazza::Doe;
    // No error
    ingre = static_cast<plazza::Ingredients>(plazza::Ingredients::Doe);
    // what I try but error
    _stock[0].ingredient = static_cast<plazza::Ingredients>(plazza::Ingredients::Doe);

}
```

Error adding into the vector of structure

```
==7692== Invalid write of size 4
==7692==    at 0x110A7E: Kitchen::Kitchen(int, int, int) (in /home/jonathangomez/epitech/2/ccp/CCP_plazza_2019/plazza)
==7692==    by 0x10CE96: Reception::time_to_work() (in /home/jonathangomez/epitech/2/ccp/CCP_plazza_2019/plazza)
==7692==    by 0x10C16B: main (in /home/jonathangomez/epitech/2/ccp/CCP_plazza_2019/plazza)
==7692==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: what error? Please include the error and a [mcve] in the quesiton

Comment: why are you casting a `plazza::Ingredients` to a `plazza::Ingredients` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I was trying to insert the value in a different way, what I tried to resolve the issue

Comment: Did you insert an element into `_stock` ? If you don't then it has none

Comment: `_stock[0]` is undefined behavior if element 0 has not yet been allocated.

Comment: @0x5453 how can I fix it?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't understand about I'm not inserting an element into `_stocks`? `_stock[0].ingredient = plazza::Doe;`

Comment: That's not how you insert an element in C++. Use [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or an initialization list instead.

Comment: @Elijan9 how can I do it? 
`_stock.push_back(plazza::Ingredients::Doe);` how I specify my vector variable ìngredients`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to _stocks[0] but you aren't sizing your vector first to contain at least one element. Either use [push_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or use an initialization list to initialize your vector at construction.

To assign something to a t_stock you can use

```
t_stock dummy = { plazza::Doe /* first argument in struct is the ingredient */, 1 /*second argument in the struct is the quantity */ }
```

Combined, to assign everything properly in your Kitchen constructor, you could use:

```
Kitchen::Kitchen(int multiplier, int numCooks, int cookingTime)
: _multiplier(multiplier), 
  _numCooks(numCooks), 
  _cookingTime(cookingTime), 
  _stock({ {plazza::Doe, 1} }) // Initialize vector with one element
{
}
```

To add multiple elements at creation you can do:

```
Kitchen::Kitchen(int multiplier, int numCooks, int cookingTime)
: _multiplier(multiplier), 
  _numCooks(numCooks), 
  _cookingTime(cookingTime), 
  _stock({ {plazza::Doe, 1}, {plazza::Tomato, 4} }) // Initialize vector with two elements
{
}
```

To add new stock elements after creation, always use `push_back`

```
_stock.push_back({plazzo::Gruyere, 16}); // Add lots of 'em
```

Comment: how can I add the rest of the ingredients?
` _stock[0].ingredient = plazza::Doe;` and
   ` _stock[1].ingredient = plazza::Tomato;`

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should never assign to an element that isn't allocated in the vector. Either use push_back to add new elements, or use [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) on the vector, then assign each new element.